# What happens to session id after session expires?

Tags: asp.net

I am new to asp.net. so i want to know:

Does session id is removed when 
session is expired ?

Does a new session id is regenerated after expiration ?

Or only session variables are removed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A session is considered active as long as requests continue to be made with the same SessionID value. If the time between requests for a particular session exceeds the specified time-out value in minutes, the session is considered expired. Requests made with an expired SessionID value result in a new session.

Refer : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.140).aspx